# How to rotate Image dynamically on its place?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I want to rotate image dynamically(Not by XML code). I am using this code to rotate the Image:

```
public void rotateAnimation(){
    // Create an animation instance
    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(30, 360);

    // Set the animation's parameters
    an.setDuration(2000);               // duration in ms
    an.setRepeatCount(0);                // -1 = infinite repeated
    an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // reverses each repeat
    an.setFillAfter(true);               // keep rotation after animation


    // Aply animation to image view
    scanCircle.setAnimation(an);
}
```

Using this code, My ImageView get rotate but its not on its position but outside to its position. I want is to rotate it on its own position.

So, How to make it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think position pivotx & pivotY will helpful http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html#RotateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29

```
RotateAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float pivotX, float pivotY)
```

suppose if you want to rotate from middle then

```
RotateAnimation(30, 360, totalWidth/2, totalHeight/2)
```

Comment: Thanks but totalWidth of which?  ImageView or the Display ?

Comment: Its not of Display, Its of the ImageView on which i want the rotate animation. its works now. Thanks.

Comment: will you help me more? I want to rotate that imageView again but from its last rotates position. not from the 0 degree position.

Comment: store that last position in some variable and on next put that variable value instead on `0`.

Comment: ok. So i have to store the Degree of last stop animation and that degree is used on starting of the another animation right ? If it so then is there any other alternate of it ?